# can i apply generics on a variable in java?

Tags: java, generics

in java we can apply generics on a class and methods as shown below

```
class Sample<T>{}
public <T,E> void test(T x, E y){}
```

this helps us write generic algorithms , help us reuse the same code for multiple inputs ,similarly can we apply generics on primitive variables?? if it is possible we can reuse the same variable again and again for different inputs , i know

```
class Sample<T>{public T temp;}
```

is possible.

but the question is

```
class Sample{public <T> T temp;}
```

is this possible

Comment: In your last example you could create different instances of that class with different `temp` types. That would defeat the type system, therefore it does not make sense to permit this syntax. You have to use `Object` in this case.

Comment: And the answer is: **no**.

Comment: Your first example is at least confusing: there are two different type variables both called `T`. If you want them to be independent, for code clarity rename one of them. If you want them to be the same, change the method declaration to read `public <E> void test(T x, E y){}`. And as E only appears as type of the second parameter, there's no benefit over simply writing `public void test(T x, Object y){}`.

Comment: thank you guys for the insight it was helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it's not, it wouldn't be possible to tell what type temp is, so it wouldn't help the compiler restrict anything (that is the point of generics), or tools to make any suggestions.

You can't get better in this case than making temp an Object. (or use your second example)